# Can't see volume when I run `ls` in teminal

Tags: 16.04, volume-control, ls, clion

this is my first problem in Ubuntu 16.04:
when I run ls in terminal as you can see

[image: picture]

I can't see my volume. I have 315 GB and 104GB volumes
and when I want to make a project in C Lion I can't see my volumes then either.

Comment: What do you mean by 'volume'?  What do you expect to see? Why do you feel that 'ls' is the proper tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ls` doesn't show you volume. It shows you files and folders withing the present working directory. By default, when you open terminal, you are at your home folder (shown as ~, located at `/home/USERNAME/`) so you get the same result as you shared.

In order to get the list of partitions, run `lsblk` which shows partitions and where they are mounted.

For example:

```
~$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   931G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   120G  0 part /media/C
├─sda3   8:3    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   780G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0    27G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here, I see on my first Harddisk, I have 7 partitions. One of them which is `sda2` has been mounted to `/media/C`. So its content can be accessed from that address by running `ls /media/C/`

If your needed partition is not mounted yet, you need to mount it. You may need to have little research for it (If you have windows on your system, you may face with little problem)

Comment: Oh thanks But why i cant make clion project in my 315GB volume ?

Comment: This is a different question. I suggest you to ask a separate question in which there be in-detail explanation of your partition (format) and the way you are trying to make the project.